# Sequelize findAll with some parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

Below is a simple query I created for sequelize. According to this query, I want to bring a category ID and products in that category in price range. But the values ​​I give are generated by the sequel as "NaN".

```js
{
  where: { urun_ust_kategori_kod: 10, urun_fiyat: { '$gt': 10, '$lt': 30 } },
  offset: 0,
  limit: 32
}
```

```
SELECT `id`, `urun_linki`, `urun_ad`, `urun_kod`, `urun_ana_kategori_kod`, `urun_xml_kod`, `urun_ust_kategori_kod`, `urun_ust_kategori_ad`, `urun_marka_kod`, `urun_kategori_ad`, `urun_kategori_kod`, `urun_marka_ad`, `urun_ucretsizKargo`, `urun_aktif`, `urun_tanim`, `urun_aciklama`, `urun_ozellikler`, `urun_resim1`, `urun_resim2`, `urun_fiyat`, `urun_fiyat_TL`, `urun_fiyat_site`, `urun_havale_fiyat_TL`, `urun_fiyat_piyasa`, `urun_kdv`, `urun_stok`, `urun_garanti`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `e_products` AS `e_product` WHERE `e_product`.`urun_ust_kategori_kod` = 10 AND (`e_product`.`urun_fiyat` = 'NaN' AND `e_product`.`urun_fiyat` = 'NaN') LIMIT 0, 32;
```

Comment: Which version Sequelize?  Things like `$gt` where deprecated a couple major version ago.

Comment: Hey bro:
  "sequelize": "^6.3.5",
How i can make between query instead $gt ?

Comment: https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators

this is v6 documentation. Used in abundance here

Comment: Those docs seems to say to use `[Op.gt]` instead of `'$gt'`. (Note that this assumes you've initialized with `const { Op } = require("sequelize");`.)